# Using conditional staements to load plugins

Tags: plugins, ajax, conditional-tags

I'm having some conflicts I think with a couple of plugins I have written that use ajax. As they load their resources on every page rather then just when needed I think it's causing problems.

What's the best way to just load a plugin when you need it? Both plugins in question only need to run when the user navigates to a single page

I just wanted to wrap a plugin in something like:

```
if (is_page( 'slug-name' ) ) {

     //plugin code

}
```

But that obviously won't work because it's outside of any Wordpress hooks.

WooCommerce has the following that only loads your WooCommerce plugin if WooCommerce itself is active, could I adapt this some how?

```
/**
 * Check if WooCommerce is active
 **/
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option(     'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    // Put your plugin code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

figured it out... The main problem with the scripts so just wrapped them in this for each plugin:

```
function my_enqueue_javascript() {
    if (is_page('page')) {
        //Include Javascript library
        wp_enqueue_script('', plugins_url( '/js/ajax.js' , __FILE__ ) , array( 'jquery' ));
        // including ajax script in the plugin Myajax.ajaxurl
        wp_localize_script( '', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_enqueue_javascript', 100 );
```